# How do I merge a feature collection contaning several feature collection into one?

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, mapping, feature-collection

Here I am trying to get a merged feature collection containing the data row-wise for the 24 extracted images but instead I get a feature collection which has 24 elements as feature collection. I want to merge these feature collections into one single feature collection.

```js
var Sentinel1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S1_GRD"),
GAUL = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2"),
geometry = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-nandlalodedara/assets/Shapefile");
```

```
var marigaon = GAUL.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_CODE',70092));
Map.addLayer(marigaon,{},'marigaonDistrict');

Map.centerObject(geometry)
Map.addLayer(geometry)
//filtering date, bounds, and images having VH band
//(few images don't have info about VH band which will trouble further calc)
var filtered= Sentinel1.filter(ee.Filter.bounds(marigaon))
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2017-01-01','2018-12-31'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .select('VH');
//print(filtered)

//setting start and end year and making list of years and months
var startYear = 2017;
var endYear = 2018;
var years = ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear);
var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);    

//filtering 24 images from 2 years and setting month and year for the same
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection(ee.FeatureCollection(years.map(function(y){
  var yearCollection = filtered.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(y, y, 'year'));
  var byYear = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
    months.map(function(m) {
      var summedImage = yearCollection.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                  .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()); 
      var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1).format("MM_dd_YYYY");
      return summedImage.set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(y, m, 1))
      .set('month', m).set('year', y); // eventually set year and month 
  }));
  return byYear;
})).flatten());

print(byMonth)

//Applying threshold to each image
var appThresh = byMonth.map(function(img) {return img.clip(marigaon).lt(-23.6)});
print(appThresh)

//finding area for the given geometry (imported shapefile)
var imgPixel = appThresh.map(function (img) {return img.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())})

var features = imgPixel.map(function (img) {return img.reduceRegions(geometry, ee.Reducer.sum(), 10)});
print(features) //features is a collection of collections


//exporting
Export.table.toDrive({collection: features, fileFormat: 'csv'});
```

Exporting this gives an error because `features` is a collection of collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export it by using "flatten" as follows:

```
var features = imgPixel.map(function (img) {
  
  return img.reduceRegions(geometry, ee.Reducer.sum(), 10);
  
}).flatten();

//exporting
Export.table.toDrive({collection: features, fileFormat: 'csv'});
```

Complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/64fdae42ca6fb694349c2bc59c640b65).

Following image was obtained after running complete code in GEE code editor. It can be observed that task was successfully finished in < 1 minute.

[image]

Comment: Hey, it worked but the exported CSV files had a problem, it contained a few unnecessary extra rows which I had to filter out manually(ex. Row No. 69, 234, 319 etc).
What might be the problem in this export case.
Here is the exported CSV file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y7tSkvQGbNEHMafNITZBZM0cdc0BSv2e/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It could be the use of reduceRegions. What is the information you truly need when you use reduceRegions? I could compare it by using reduceRegion instead.

Comment: I attached the wrong file in my previous comment, attached below is the file I was talking about [Monthly Area17-18] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TZnAZ1EeO-BR-2xjoQyfjIXpPZzZ49pm/view?usp=sharing)
I had to filter out manually(ex. Row No. 69, 234, 319 etc) I am trying to find the area of water bodies by using the reduceRegions

Comment: By the way, when you are trying with this kind of files is inevitable to filter out manually some data; especially geometry column. As you have 24x248 records (5952), your CSV file must have 5953 rows; including first record of column names. So, I got your CSV file running the task, deleted geom geometry and my CSV has not any problem referred to extra records. This is my link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lrfaPChFrhowOrMmzQaeTg_G3zopK8GR/view?usp=sharing